# store string in object as new variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the code below:

```
binance.depth("GTOBTC", (error, depth, symbol) => {
console.log(depth.bids);
})
```

This outputs:

```
'0.00003061': 481,
'0.00003050': 100,
'0.00003047': 330,
'0.00003046': 395,
'0.00003044': 1000,
```

I would like to loop through this object and store the string value before the ':' into a temporary variable.

Comment: Please, post the content of `depth.bids`

Comment: im unable as im using an api

Comment: can you add expected output?

Comment: console.log(depth.bids.keys()); what does this returns?

Comment: i was hoping to iterate through the object and store the string into var tempName

Comment: Check the answer given by Jeremy it should work. I was trying to be sure before answering.

Comment: console.log(depth.bids.keys());  this gives me depth is undefined

Comment: if depth is undefined then where did the output came from?

Comment: console.log(Object.keys(depth.bids)); try this

Comment: Use Object.keys you will get all the keys in object that you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the string value before the ':'` is called a key, and you access an object's keys using `Object.keys()`. In your case :

```
let keys = Object.keys(depth.bids) // ['0.00003061', '0.00003050', etc. ]

for( let key of keys ){
   // First pass key=='0.00003061', second pass key=='0.00003050'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of an object.

```
var bids = {'0.00003061': 481,
'0.00003050': 100,
'0.00003047': 330,
'0.00003046': 395,
'0.00003044': 1000
};

var keys = Object.keys(bids );
// output: ["0.00003061", "0.00003050", "0.00003047", "0.00003046", "0.00003044"]
```